# access firestore from firebase-functions using web version 9 interface (modular)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have to access a firestore database within firebase functions.
I use the following code to get a firestore instance:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app"
initializeApp();

import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
const db = getFirestore();
```

This instance can be used to access the database

```
db.collection('test').add( { anything: 123 } )
db.collection('test').doc('test123').set( { afield: 1234 } )
db.collection('test').doc('test123').get()
```

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-8 this is "Web version 8 (namespaced)" interface for accessing firestore databases.

How can I use the "Web version 9 (modular)" interface? The version 9 example from the same page:

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");
```

results in the following error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Is there a way to query firestore with admin privileges using modular interface?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

The Admin SDK does not use functional syntax totally yet. The `Web version 8/9` are client SDK. Refer to `NodeJS` tab of the documentation when using Firebase Admin SDK.

Also you are importing `collection()` from Firebase client SDK but it seems the `db` is initialized using `getFirestore()` from Firebase SDK that might not work properly.